# Is it possible to retrieve schema change information in Dynamics CRM online?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

When a custom entity is created, a field is added or changed, someone makes an out-of-box changes to metadata.

**How to know who did it and when?**

The same for the creation or modification from a UI form. The metadata in CRM doesn't seem to store that information.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to access information you're asking for. Such a information is not available in the on-premise CRM database and I suppose there is a similar situation with CRM Online

Comment: Thanks Piotr, I thought as much and will have to do something custom.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are looking for. But this will be a good starting point to achieve what you want.

Using [RetrieveMetadataChangesRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863599.aspx#BKMK_RetrievingNeworChangedMetadata), we can get the schema changes like:

- Adding a custom entity named sample_SampleEntityForMetadataQuery with
  a custom optionset attribute named : sample_ExampleOptionSet
- ClientVersionStamp: 296646!10/22/2012 21:42:06
- Adding an additional option to the sample_ExampleOptionSet attribute
  options
- Deleting the sample_SampleEntityForMetadataQuery custom entity

--

[Sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863605.aspx) can be found in MSDN/SDK.

```
 protected RetrieveMetadataChangesResponse getMetadataChanges(
                         EntityQueryExpression entityQueryExpression,
                         String clientVersionStamp,
                         DeletedMetadataFilters deletedMetadataFilter)
{
 RetrieveMetadataChangesRequest retrieveMetadataChangesRequest = new RetrieveMetadataChangesRequest()
 {
  Query = entityQueryExpression,
  ClientVersionStamp = clientVersionStamp,
  DeletedMetadataFilters = deletedMetadataFilter
 };

 return (RetrieveMetadataChangesResponse)_service.Execute(retrieveMetadataChangesRequest);

}
```

Comment: The version stamp: "ClientVersionStamp: 296646!10/22/2012 21:42:06" where it comes from?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrievemetadatachangesrequest.clientversionstamp.aspx